Can I use bullet pavers for a short walkway
I recently got about 150 bullet pavers for free off FB marketplace. Originally I was gonna just edge up a section but with so many I figured I could make a walkway.
I only need a section like 1ft x 15ft for a small path from the front porch to the sidewalk as a short cut to the mailbox. If I dig down and do all the standard paver prep it should be fine right? I'd Probably stick the plastic edger hold on place thing on either side but would this work?
Everywhere I look bullet pavers are only used as an edge like trim piece.
Also like 15 of them look like some oil or something got spilled on them and stained. Would muraric acid clean that out or what would work to get oil out of concrete?

For oil, a solution of hot water and washing soda (sodium carbonate) and soak them in it would be a first step.

The key question is whether the tops are flat or curved/domed. If they are flat then this will work fine. If they are curved then it will make for a very uncomfortable - and possibly unsafe - walkway.
I also recommend wider than 1', if you have the space for it. 1' is awfully narrow. Of course, a lot depends on the size of the pavers. A typical size seems to be ~ 12" x 4". At that size, 150 would pave 50 square feet - enough for 15' x 2' (which is reasonably wide for a basic pathway) and 20 square feet leftover. But the sizes vary by style and manufacturer, and the size may include space used to nest one piece in another. So if the "real" size turns out to be ~ 10" x 3" then 150 will be 31 square feet and just barely enough for 15' x 2'. In other words, YMMV.

If they're flat top, the proper prep would really be no different than a brick sidewalk, and those work fine.  You'd just be working with non-rectangular pieces, which would limit you to a linear orientation of the edgers, rather than possibly decorative patterns if you used regular rectangular bricks.

Yeah they are the flat ones they are 3.75 wide 3.5 tall and 13 long but if you remove the rounded bite from either side it's basically 12". I could do 5 wide which would be about 18" wide

@Milwrdfan yup flat ones, I plan on going in a straight line because straight lines are much easier than wavy things lol. I have a diamond saw for cutting them so when I get to the far side I can easily cut the last ones to size and get the perfect snug fit.
